# Can struct statx be used inside kernel?

Tags: c, linux, struct, linux-kernel

I'm trying to get a particular process' creation time. In order to do that I use vfs_statx() method which takes struct kstat as an argument. But the problem is that does the struct kstat has struct statx_timestamp field inside it? I know that struct statx does have it, but can it be used within kernel?

Shortly:

Can I define a variable like `struct statx my_stat;` inside kernel and then use its statx_timestamp field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would the kernel fill in times if it didn't already have this defined?  timespec is defined here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.29/source/include/uapi/linux/time.h#L9

Comment: kstat is here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.29/source/include/linux/stat.h#L21

Comment: In the vfs_statx() definition the method itself takes an argument of type kstat, and it's used to give more information about the specified file than vfs_stat() does.
Here is the function's definiton: 
int vfs_statx(int dfd, const char __user *filename, int flags,
       struct kstat *stat, u32 request_mask)

Comment: Here's the definition link: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/fs/stat.c#L168